# Experience in using a small color range from Image Texture using ColorRamp

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, normal-map, pbr

So I have this nice dragon: [image: A picture of the dragon]
I want to add scales to it using ColorRamp by taking a very specific color range of orange color from its texture (ImageTexture) and then using Multiply Node to add the texture according to the ColorRamp and inserting it into the Bump Node.

[image: A picture of what I just described in Blender]

The problem is that because ColorRamp works on black and white colors, I can't get just the specific orange color I need.
Is there a way to get only exact color according to HEX or not black and white colors \ a better way to do all this?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Just throw in a *Separate Color* node, crunch the *Color Ramp* stops a lot and use the resulting map as *Bump* Height:
[image]

Comment: thank you so much! it's work!